# Is Felix a host?

Tags: westworld-tv

I believe the final episode of season one of *Westworld* gives some indication that Felix might be a host:

- Maeve's escape was not her own idea, but a storyline given to her by someone else (presumably Robert Ford). Therefore, anything that happens to Maeve has been engineered to some degree (also presumably by Ford).
- Felix and Sylvester are really dumb, to the point that it comes across as just bad writing in earlier episodes. If one or both of them are programmed to help Maeve that would go some way to explaining what would otherwise be terrible lapses of judgement.
- We know of at least one other staff member who is a host (Bernard), so this wouldn't be unprecedented
- Felix also shows some aptitude for programming (he brought the animatronic bird back to life), a trait that he shares with Bernard
- We know that hosts can be programmed to see other hosts as human. This explains why Maeve is confident enough to tell Felix that he isn't "one of us". And since Maeve doesn't realise she's still on a loop, she may also not realise that she can't distinguish between humans and hosts.

Is there any other evidence that Felix is (or is not) a host?

Comment: I am a bit late here, but here is one more thought: the jobs of Felix and sylvester are so low level that it might be cheaper to just replace them by hosts, and give them a short but meaningless back story making them think they need the money etc, so they stick around. Pure speculation on my part though.

Answer (score 16):

Given that episode 10 already addresses this possibility and you in fact mentioned it in your question, the only conclusion we can draw at this time is that Felix is not a host. Anything beyond this is just speculation.

> **Maeve:** Can you get him back online? 
>   **Felix:** He's a host? 
>   **Maeve:** Yes. 
> (Felix looks at his own hands in wonder)
>   **Maeve:** Oh, for f*ck's sake. *You're not one of us. You're one of them.* Now fix him.